# React Native - elevation shadow not covering all View

Tags: css, react-native, elevation

My `View`'s shadow not covering all the outside but just the top and the bottom:

[image: pic]

Here is the style:

```
 root: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 5,
    paddingTop: 22,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 16,
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  }
```

How can I make the shadow to cover all the View?

Answer (score 0):

You should give marginHorizonal in your root style.